# when the main return nothing, Why I got the return value of the last func called by main in linux c?

Tags: c, linux, program-entry-point

here is my code in linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int tt(void);
static int tt(void)
{
  return 1;
}
int main(int charc,char **charv)
{
  tt();
}
```

in the shell:

```
$./a.out
$echo %?
$1
```

Why i got the "1" as the result

Comment: @usr Nopes, it is not.

Comment: Not a dupe (of that question) @usr.  The issue here is that the program returns a different exit status than the standard says it ought to do.

Comment: It is. It's question of whether OP compiles in C99 (or later) or before - in that case, it's *undefined behaviour* which is what I suspect. It's basically not understanding what main returns/supposed to return and/or C99 vs. eariler. There are a lot of info covered in the linked question. Have you read them all and concluded it's not?

Comment: @usr Agreed, I'll close this as a duplicate. The accepted answer in the duplicate addresses the `return` from main() issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning from a non-void function without returning a value is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You can't depend on the result.

There is a special case for the `main` function starting with the C99 standard.  If no value is returned from `main`, a return value of 0 is assumed.  However,  you appear to be compiling in C89 mode (which is the default for gcc) where this is not allowed.

If I compile this code as C89, I get a warning about not returning a value.  To demonstrate undefined behavior, if I compile without optimizations the exit status is 1, but if I compile with `-O3` the exit status is 96.

If I compile in C99 mode I get no warning and the exit status of the program is 0.

To compile in C99 mode, pass the flag `-std=c99` to gcc.

Comment: yes. i got it . thanks

Comment: @ccw Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.